# Exercise 1.5.7 in Weibel's book about mapping cone and mapping cylinder

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Given a short exact sequence of chain complexes
$$0\rightarrow B \xrightarrow{\ f\ }C \xrightarrow{\ g\ }D\rightarrow 0$$
The problem asks to show that there is a quasi-isomorphism $B[-1]\rightarrow \mathrm{cone}(g)$. And showing that the composite 
$$H_{n}(D)\xrightarrow{\ \partial\ }H_{n-1}(B) \xrightarrow{\ \simeq\ }H_{n}(\mathrm{cone}(g))$$
is the usual map induced by the inclusion of $D$ in $\mathrm{cone}(g)$.

The only map I can image from $B[-1]$ to $\mathrm{cone}(g)$ is given by $b\mapsto (f(b), 0)$. However, I can't show that it is a quasi-isomorphism directly or put it into a commutative digram of short exact sequences. Can anyone give me some hints?

I am pretty sure that we will use the short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow C \rightarrow \mathrm{cone}(f) \rightarrow B[-1] \rightarrow 0$$
other two short exact sequences that might be helpful are
$$0\rightarrow D \rightarrow \mathrm{cone}(g) \rightarrow C[-1] \rightarrow 0$$
and 
$$0\rightarrow C \rightarrow \mathrm{cyl}(g) \rightarrow \mathrm{cone}(g)  \rightarrow 0$$
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quasi-isomorphism $\psi:B[-1]\to\mathrm{cone}(g)$ is $b\mapsto(-f(b),0)$.

We do indeed use some of your suggested short exact sequences. Consider the diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
&&&&0&\ra{}&B[-1]&\ra{f}&C[-1]&\ra{g}&D[-1]&\ra{}&0\\
&&&&&&\da{\psi}&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&&&\\
&&0&\ra{}&D&\ra{\iota}&\mathrm{cone}(g)&\ra{\delta}&C[-1]&\ra{}&0\\
&&&&\da{}&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&&&&&\\
0&\ra{}&C&\ra{}&\mathrm{cyl}(g)&\ra{}&\mathrm{cone}(g)&\ra{}&0
\end{array}
$$
which creates homology long exact sequences
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
\cdots&\ra{}&H_{n+1}(C[-1])&\ra{}&H_{n+1}(D[-1])&\ra{\partial}&H_{n}(B[-1])&\ra{}&H_{n}(C[-1])&\ra{}&\cdots\\
&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&\da{\psi_{*}}&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&\\
\cdots&\ra{}&H_{n+1}(C[-1])&\ra{\partial}&H_{n}(D)&\ra{\iota_{*}}&H_{n}(\mathrm{cone}(g))&\ra{}&H_{n}(C[-1])&\ra{\partial}&\cdots\\
&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&\da{\cong}&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&\da{\mathrm{id}}&&\\
\cdots&\ra{\partial}&H_{n}(C)&\ra{}&H_{n}(\mathrm{cyl}(g))&\ra{}&H_{n}(\mathrm{cone}(g))&\ra{\partial}&H_{n-1}(C)&\ra{}&\cdots
\end{array}
$$
By the five lemma, $\psi$ is a quasi-isomorphism. By the commutativity of the homology diagram at the top middle square,
$$
\partial:H_{n}(D)\to H_{n-1}(B)
$$
is the map
$$
H_{n}(D)\xrightarrow{\iota_{*}}H_{n}(\mathrm{cone}(g))\cong H_{n-1}(B),
$$
where $\iota_{*}$ is the map induced by the inclusion $D\xrightarrow{\iota}\mathrm{cone}(g)$.

Comment: To apply five lemma, we need to guarantee the commutativity of all the squares. So maybe we should at first verify that the top middle square is commutative? Or is it guaranteed by naturality?

Comment: @ZichenGao Depending on your familiarity with the subject (if you're working through Weibel section 1.5, for instance), it might be good to verify the square is commutative explicitly, but yes, it is guaranteed by naturality. A map of SESs is a commutative ladder, and it induces a commutative ladder of LESs under homology. A good exercise to do if you're not familiar with it! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that a morphism between short exact sequence induces a commutative ladder of LESs, but I think the way you constructed the homology long exact sequences was not exactly the same as the LESs induced by chain maps between SESs, since what we have is only one commtative square between the first two rows of SESs in your answer. Or is there a generalized version of this “snake lemma”?